# how can we come to know that which frame work is missing in our code

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have got some code from my client.
I have tried to build that code but it gave following error
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1

There are many frameworks and libraries used in this project.

How can we come to know which file or framework is missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure the error is about a framework? If you look closely at the error message in *Build Results*, there should be more info about it (if you click on a disclosure button on the message's right).

Here's a screenshot from Xcode 3.
[image: A detailed error log]

Comment: I think Alex more meant you to show us your errors, not just tell us that you have some. Add a screenshot to your question!